# Construct $PATH by listing the directories in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following folder structure

```
~/lib
~/lib/opencv
-/lib/leptonica
```

I need to construct a variable, let's say `$PATH` by listing the `~/lib` directory.
The `~/opencv` and `~/leptonica` directories will contain the files to be included in the path.

Finally, my `$PATH` should contain

```
~/lib/opencv:~/lib/leptonica
```

Comment: Why do you want to include single files into your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? I don't see a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for

```
PATH=$(printf '%s:' ~/lib/*/)"$PATH"
```

This will prepend those two directories to the current value of `PATH`.

You really do not want to remove system directories like `/bin`, `/usr/bin` etc from your `PATH` variable.

If `~/lib` is guaranteed to *only* contain directories, you can trim off the trailing slash from the wildcard; but I would keep it just to be on the safe side and explicit about what this is supposed to do.  The trailing slashes in the final value are technically superfluous, but harmless.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use full path if you are going to use this for whole system

```
export PATH=$PATH:/<yourhomepath>/lib/opencv:/<yourhomepath>/lib/leptonica
```